# Why $u(x)=-\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{2\pi^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb R^n}|x-y|^{1-n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k-y_k}{|x-y|}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_k}(y)dy$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u\in \mathcal C_c^1(\mathbb R^n)$. Why
 $$u(x)=-\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{2\pi^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb R^n}|x-y|^{1-n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k-y_k}{|x-y|}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_k}(y)dy \ \ ?$$

where does it come from ? God ? Is there a theorem that tell us that ?

Answer (score 1):

We suppose WLOG that $x=0$. Let $R>0$ s.t. $\text{Supp}(u)\subset B_R(0)=:B_R$.
\begin{align*}
u(0)= \int_0^R \partial _r u(\sigma r)dr
\end{align*}
and thus, integrating over $\partial B_1$ and using Fubini, we get
\begin{align*}
u(0)&= \frac{1}{|\partial B_1|}\int_0^R\int_{\partial B_1} \partial _r u(\sigma r)d\sigma dr \\
&\underset{y=r\sigma }{=}\frac{1}{|\partial B_1|}\int_0^R\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_r}\partial _r u(y)dydr\\
&=\frac{1}{|\partial B_1|}\int_{B_R}\frac{1}{|y|^{n-1}}\nabla u(y)\cdot \frac{y}{|y|}dy.
\end{align*}

Letting $R\to \infty $ and using the fact that $|\partial B_1|=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$ gives you the wished result.